# Google Data studio can't find the bigquery dataset after moving to a different location

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have changed the location of several datasets in bigquery. The final names have not been changed after the operation.

I can query them in the bigquery UI but data studio is raising an error (BigQuery error: Not found: Dataset xxx:yyy)

It seems that data studio is not changing the processing location.

Is there a fix or solution for this?

Comment: It is not really clear, what you did when running into the problem. Please elaborate and/or add some code.

Comment: Given a working dashboard in data studio pulling data from dataset A in bigquery, located in USA:

> I created a dataset B located in EU
> I transferred data from A to B (data transfer in bigquery)
> I removed dataset A in USA
> I created a new dataset A but now in EU
> I transferred data from  to B to A (data transfer in bigquery)

Comment: My expectation is that the dashboard will continue working without any problem  since the dataset name was preserved.

The actual issue is that data studio can not see the new dataset, thus the dashboard is not loading at all.

> Running a query directly in bigquery UI works
> Other tools querying that data work without any change at all


So, it seems that data studio is still running with a processor location based in USA and, therefore, is unable to connect to the dataset new location.

Comment: Also encountering this issue. Did you figure out how to resolve it?

Comment: I could not find a way to solve it. Apparently, the processor location in bigquery is still working on the first location, even though you move the data to a different one.

The only solution I found is to remove the data source in data studio and add them again.

This may break your dashboards since you will face a different problem (re-engaging charts with a new dataset), please be careful with that. Especially all calculated fields on charts (data studio won't display them if the source data is not ok).

https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/131834587?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved this bug without breaking my dashboards.

1. Click on "Resource" -> "Manage added data sources";
2. Find the data source that you need to reconnect and "Edit" it;
3. Click on "Edit Connection" on top-left;
4. Click on "Custom Query" and use this template: SELECT * FROM `{project}.{dataset}.{table}`
5. Click on "Reconnect";

By doing this, you can preserve all your fields & tables.

After that, you can use it just like that or move back to selecting the dataset and table and reconnect again.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this and "Reconnect" does not work.  The fix is to Copy the report, then it will work.  Rename the old report with a (Do Not Use) suffix, then remove "Copy of" from your new report name.

You will need to reset the Share permissions to the same as the old report. Of course any links to the old report need to change too.

Answer (score 0):

"Reconnect" works when you connect a new table and then back to the previous table.